# Are SDE adapted to the natural filtration?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-paths

Let $(B^H_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ be a fractional Brownian motion. We consider the following SDE where $b$ and $\sigma$ are Lipschitz
$$X_t=x+\int_0^t b(X_s)ds+\int_0^t\sigma(X_s)dB^H_s.$$
When $H>1/2$, the equation is in the Young's sence. and for $1/2<H<1/4$ is in rough path sence.
My question: is the solution (i.e., $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$) adapted to the natural filtration?

Comment: Yes, as is more or less obvious from uniqueness and the construction of solutions. Note that Lipschitz isn't enough for $\sigma$, you'll need at least $C^\alpha$ for $\alpha> 1/H$ to get unique solutions in general.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It was helpful.